# .htaccess has no effect on subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache2, .htpasswd

I need to protect my whole website (It's just for development at the moment) with a password. So I created a `.htaccess` and a `.htpassword` file. The `.htaccess` contains

```
AuthUserFile /my/absolute/path/.htpassword
AuthName "Protected"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

My directory tree looks like this

```
/var/www
|--- file.php
|--- .htaccess
|--- dir
|   |--- text.html
|--- file2.php
```

If I try to access `file.php` or `file2.php` (any file which is directly in `/var/www`), the webpage is protected by the password. However, I can access the file in the subdirectory (`/dir/text.html`) without any authentication. I'm absolutely certain that there's no `.htaccess` in `/var/www/dir` (I use `ls -A`).

I've seen on the web that `.htaccess` is supposed to have an effect on the directory and ALL subfolders, and that's what I want.

Do you know why it doesn't have any effect on the file in subdirectory in my case? If so, how can I make it work?

Comment: Your basic authentication in the `.htaccess` file in the document root _should_ affect the entire directory tree, unless you have other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories (or `<Directory>` containers in the server config) that override this. However, if you've previously accessed `/dir/text.html` before you implemented the authentication then it's possible you are seeing a cached response. (?) Make sure all local caches are cleared (try a different browser). Is there a proxy server on the network?

Comment: How about `/var/www/text.html`? Does it require authentication?

Comment: I feel so stupid it was a cache problem... The thing that was weird is that it did ask again for file.php but not for text.html. Anyway it works, thanks MrWhite.

Answer (score -1):

you can write custom code in php for session login 
and forbidden rest access 
on header

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{echo "do the stuff";}
else
{header("location:login");}
```

Comment: I don't want anybody to access the website even the login page. So I can't use php. And .htaccess features are perfect for what I want to do

Comment: <Files ~ "\.php$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. I should place <Files ~ "\.php$"> Order allow,deny Deny from all </Files>  in my htaccess ?

Comment: This answer does not address the specific problem in the question. (Also, simply adding that `<Files>` directive will simply block _everyone_?!)

Answer (score -1):

If you have static ip, you can simply allow access to website only from one IP in your virtual host config:

`<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 #your IP
</Directory>`

Comment: Multiple IP will access it and these IP can change at anytime, it's not a solution. Besides it doesn't help with the problem I have : Your .htaccess will still not have effect on subdirectory

Comment: @Peni "Your .htaccess will still not have effect on subdirectory" - Ollie's code (in it's current state) is intended to go in the server config, not `.htaccess` - but this _should_ affect subdirectories, just as your password-protect code _should_ also affect subdirectories.

Comment: Sorry it was a missclick, I unmarked it. Oh ok  i didn't understand it was for server configuration. And yes it should affect subdirectories but I have no idea why it doesn't work... Of course I could copy past my .htaccess in every directory but I don't think that's an acceptable solution.